# NSString initWithBytesNoCopy returns nil while using NSUTF32StringEncoding encoding

Tags: c++, nsstring, objective-c++, foundation, nsstringencoding

I am developing a bridge between C++ and Swift. So I need to convert C++ u32 string into swift String. Here is the problematic code:

```
    int count = linesProvider->getDisplayLinesCount();
    NSMutableArray *lines = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:static_cast<NSUInteger>(count)];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        std::u32string_view line = linesProvider->getDisplayedLineAt(i);
        NSString* objCline = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:(void*)line.data()
                                                            length:line.size() * sizeof(char32_t)
                                                          encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding freeWhenDone:NO];
        [lines addObject:objCline];
    }
```

While debugging I found out, that objCline is nil. What am doing wrong?

Here is how I debug this:
[image]

Comment: What is `linesProvider->getDisplayedLineAt(i)`?

Answer (score 0):

Is your string data accepted if you use the `initWithBytes:` variant of the method?

The reason for the failure is either that you're supplying string data that `CFString` does not like (in which case the above copying variant would also fail), or that `CFString` simply does not support UTF-32 as an internal representation, so they must always be copied. I suspect the latter.

If you feel like finding out for sure, you can trawl through the source for an older version of the `CFStringCreateWithBytesNoCopy()` function (which is what the `NSString` ultimately calls down to) here:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1151.16/CFString.c.auto.html

It calls down to the rather long `__CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3()` function, which will take a while to unpick. You could compile your own version of that function and step through it in the debugger to find out which condition is causing the `return NULL` in your case.

(As an aside, I suspect the `…NoCopy` semantics will be difficult to uphold safely in a general purpose Swift wrapper, so allowing the copy might be the better approach anyway - for example, `CFString` assumes the memory that is passed in will never be modified, which of course is not necessarily true for a C++ string.)

Comment: I've tried initWithBytes and the result is the same.

Comment: @SemyonTikhonenko In that case, I recommend trying to reduce your code down to an example that we can reproduce in isolation.